# Observe an element's entry in viewport once with IntersectionObserver in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a function to animate elements when getting into viewport but I would like to change it so it will do it only once...I/m not sure how/where to edit to accomplish this...any advice?

```js
function useIsInViewport(ref) {
  const [isIntersecting, setIsIntersecting] = useState(false);

  const observer = useMemo(
    () =>
      new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) =>
        setIsIntersecting(entry.isIntersecting),
      ),
    [],
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    observer.observe(ref.current);

    return () => {
      observer.disconnect();
    };
  }, [ref, observer]);

  return isIntersecting;
}
```

On page I use a const for setting:

```js
const ref1 = useRef(null);
const isInViewport1 = useIsInViewport(ref1);
```

Then setting a class on the element:

```
${isInViewport1 && "fadeInDown"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `observer.unobserve(entry.target)` after the first iteration. Like below in in your specific case:

```js
function useIsInViewport(ref) {
  const [isIntersecting, setIsIntersecting] = useState(false);

  const observer = useMemo(
    () =>
      new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
        setIsIntersecting(entry.isIntersecting);
        observer.unobserve(entry.target); // line I added
      }),
    []
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    observer.observe(ref.current);

    return () => {
      observer.disconnect();
    };
  }, [ref, observer]);

  return isIntersecting;
}
```

Comment: I've chnaged it to
setIsIntersecting(entry.isIntersecting),
observer.unobserve(entry.target)
but that gives the error: 'entry' is not defined

Comment: Why you changed it? Cause it didn't work?

Comment: Because React is giving an error when using semicolon instead of a comma

Comment: Do you have `{` as I did?

Comment: Glad I could help. Though I think my comment `// line I added` is the reason why you did what you did. I should have mentioned I changed `()` to `{}`.

Comment: Hi @KnapLelijk, you can accept the answer if it has helped you. This will guide others.